# check that a window is opened in RCPTT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-rcptt

I want to check if after some actions, a window is opened.
The window name is "Help - Test". Below is my code:

```
with [get-window "Help - Test"] {
    get-property "isEnabled()" | equals true | verify-true
    get-property "isVisible()" | equals true | verify-true
}
```

when running the test I get error **The Window "Help - Test" could not be found.**

Also I tested the Eclipse help to check that the help menu is opened after Tips and Tricks and same problem:
[image: ec]

Note: I want to check that the help menu from eclipse is opened.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
get-window "Help - Test"
```

is the test itself. No need  for additional property getters. If RCPTT can not find the window then it is either not there (test case found a real problem) or it checks too early; before the window is rendered.

If the latter then things get a little complicated, you could `wait` or `wait-until-eclipse-is-ready` or place the action into a `try` section.

Comment: It still display window not found, even after adding wait and I see that the window is opened. Do you know how I get all the child windows of the parent?

Comment: Is it the standard Eclipse IDE Help window that is opening? If so, then it is not a child window but a separate workbench.

Comment: Is the help window of eclipse. How can I check for a workbench? The recorder generates code with get-window, hou can I check the workbench?